# Self-Referential Proof

Tags: turing-machines, undecidability

The theorem that "all languages are undecidable" offers the self-referential program as evidence in its proof, assuming that there exists a decider that decides L. The goal is to disproof this proof as it is not true that all languages are undecidable.

Comment: We discourage "please check whether my answer is correct" questions, as only "yes/no" answers are possible, which won't help you or future visitors. See [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/519/). Can you edit your post to ask about a specific conceptual issue you're uncertain about? As a rule of thumb, a good conceptual question should be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the problem you happen to be working on. If you just need someone to check your work, you might seek out a friend, classmate, or teacher.

Comment: Don't use images as main content of your post. This makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired; [we don't like that](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/752/should-we-do-anything-about-questions-that-are-just-a-scan-of-a-problem-in-their). Please transcribe text and mathematics (note that you can [use LaTeX](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands)) and don't forget to give proper attribution to your sources!

Comment: Thanks for the input. I am new the platform and trying to learn the rules. I tried deleting the post, and apparently cannot.

Comment: Rather than just removing the image (and leaving no context), it would be better to transcribe the relevant parts of the math, as suggested above.

Comment: After the edit, the question is now incomprehensible - I can't understand what you are asking.  I don't see a question here.  Also you refer to a proof without showing us the proof, so I don't see how we can answer any question about the proof.

Answer (score 1):

The mistake is that the function `willAccept` doesn't necessarily halt, and so this program doesn't have to accept or reject — there is a third possibility, namely, that it never terminates. In fact, this proof shows that `willAccept` is not computable.

Comment: actually, willAccept is defined to be a decider so we are allowed to assume that it always halts.

Comment: Unfortunately, this assumption leads to a contradiction. You might as well assume that 0=1.

Comment: well, reaching a contradiction is the whole idea with self-referential proofs. It is not the problem that is being asked here. Anyways, thank you for the feedback.